# How to get $\sum_i \sigma_i^2 (v_k \cdot x)^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I try to prove that for symmetric matrix $M$ with eigenvalues $\sigma_1>\sigma_2>..>\sigma_n$, then
$$
\|M\|_2=\sup_{|x|=1}\|Mx\|=\sigma_1
$$

Since $M=\sum v_iv_i^T \sigma_i$, we know that
$$
\|Mx\|^2=\sum_i v_iv_i^T \sigma_ix \cdot v_iv_i^T \sigma_ix=\sum_i \sigma_i^2 v_iv_i^T x \cdot v_iv_i^T x
$$

But why is this one equal to $\sum_i \sigma_i^2 (v_k \cdot x)^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, the statement in general is false, $||M||_2 = |\sigma_1|$, where $\sigma_1$ is the largest in absolute value eigenvalue, not the largest eigenvalue.

General sketch that goes a completely different direction but I think is much easier (in my personal opinion), assuming you are working over the reals (the complex case should work similarly with replacing symmetric matrices with Hermitian ones):

Step 1: Prove that for an orthogonal matrix $S$ (i.e. $S^TS = I$), and an arbitrary matrix $T$ such that the multiplication is defined, $||ST||_2 = ||T||_2$, and similarly for orthogonal matrix $T$ and arbitrary matrix $S$, $||ST||_2 = ||S||_2$.  To prove this, use the fact that orthogonal matrices preserve norms (why?), i.e. $||Sx|| = ||x||$ for orthogonal S, and that they are invertible, which allows you to expand the supremum definition of $||S||_2$ you gave to get the result fairly immediately.

Step 2: By the spectral theorem for symmetric matrices, as discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix#Real_symmetric_matrices), you can write any symmetric matrix $M$ as $M = P^TDP$ for diagonal $D$ and orthogonal $P$. Apply step 1 twice to get that $||M||_2 = ||D||_2$.

Step 3:
Recall that the diagonal entries of a diagonal matrix are its eigenvalues. Apply $D$ to the standard basis vectors $(e_1, \dots, e_n)$ (which are of norm 1) and take norms to get that the absolute value of $D$'s diagonal entries $|\sigma_1|, \dots, |\sigma_n|$ are in the set $\{||Dx|| \mid ||x|| = 1\}$, and let $x = [x_1, \dots, x_n]^T$ be an arbitrary vector of norm 1. Use the fact that $$||Dx||^2 \leq |\sigma_1|^2(x_1^2 + \dots + x_n^2) = |\sigma_1|^2$$ (why?) where $\sigma_1$ is the largest-in-absolute-value eigenvalue to bound (above) the above set by $|\sigma_1|$. Therefore, since we proved $|\sigma_1|$ is in the set and is an upper bound, it's the supremum.

Comment: I am a little bit confused about $\|M\|_2=\|D\|_2$. We know that $\|M\|_2=P^TDPP^TDP=P^TD^2P$. But why this one is $D^2$?

Comment: We know that $||M||_2 = ||P^TDP||_2$ (since $M = P^TDP$).  But $P$ and $P^T$ are orthogonal, so applying both parts of step 1 we get that $||M||_2 = ||P^TDP||_2 = ||P^TD||_2 = ||D||_2$.